# Wordpress style.php won't fully load

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website for an architect with large images being a main feature of the site. Given the potential size of the images I wanted to have a way to create responsive image sizing (and of course I thought of css and background images. I thought I could use CSS to build the small image as the default and as screen width increases use media queries to add larger background images).

The site is being built on wordpress - and my thought was to use a separate style.php and write a script that looped through the images to create a slide show.

A few notes: I'm using flexslider as an image slider and Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types to create "architectural projects" with featured images to create the slideshow and using my functions.php file to auto create multiple sizes for the background images.

My wordpress image slider is created with the following loop:

```
 <section class="slider slider-major" id="slider-major">

    <?php   
       $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'projects'
       ));
    ?>

    <div class="RMA-slider slider-main slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">

        <ul class="slides">

            <?php
                $slideNumber = 0;     // Set Slide numbering to 0

                while (has_sub_field('project_slider_images')) :

                $slideNumber++;
            ?>

            <li>
                <div class="slider-image slide-<?php echo $slideNumber ?>">
                </div>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

All of this works, the code I use in my style.php to loop through the image data is as follows:

```
 <?php
  $temp_post = $post;
  $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'projects'
  ));


  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();


  $slideNumber = 0;

  while (has_sub_field('project_slider_images')) :

  $slideNumber++;

  $attachment_id = get_sub_field('project_slider_image');
  $sizeSm = "slider-image-sm";
  $sizeMd = "slider-image-md";
  $sizeLg = "slider-image-Lg";// (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
  $image_attributes_sm = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeSm );
  $image_attributes_md = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeMd );
  $image_attributes_lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeLg );

?>


.slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
  background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_sm[0]; ?>");
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>{
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 100em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_lg[0]; ?>");
  }
}

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Again, this works perfectly. I loop through the project images and spit out multiple sizes to create responsive background images for the slide show.

Here's the problem: the whole css file will not load. It only seems to load the first 30 to 35 images in the style.php before it stops running through the loop and spitting out css to create the slideshows. So, the first few projects that were created work perfectly, but any of the recent projects just show blank slides, without any images having ever been looped through in the style.php to be created.

Now, I know I've given up some control by using style.php since I can't cache the files. But in my estimation is was better for load time to give up caching in favor of quick mobile load times. However, it's a moot point if the entire CSS file will not load.

Is there a specific load order I need to use? Or, can I force load the entire style.php file before anything else gets loaded? I'm still learning WordPress, but in all my reading I hadn't heard of any stlye.php loading problems (of course I've never seen it used like this).

[A link to a page that doesn't fully load the style.php file](http://www.robertmaschke.com/projects/emsheimer-residence/)

[A link to a page that does load the style.php early enough to show the images](http://www.robertmaschke.com/projects/student-enrollment-center/)

***Update****

After more testing I know now that the problem is definitely in the style.php file which is only used to set-up the sliders. I have two stylesheets: 1) normal-styles.css and 2) style.php - A dynamic stylesheet that pulls images from the wordpress database and puts them into the dynamic stylesheet as background images.

The problem is that the loop doesn't run enough times and I can't figure out why?

I've enqueued the stylesheets with the dynamic stylesheet getting precedents, but no change. The entire dynamic stylesheet is below. I have 3 different sliders running and therefore there are 3 slider loops created:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 100;
$ExpStr = "Expires" . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
$url = $parse_uri[0];

require_once($url . 'wp-load.php' );
require_once($url . 'wp-includes/post.php');
require_once($url . 'wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
require_once($url . 'wp-content/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php');

?>


/* ___________MAIN SLIDER IMAGE SET-UP______________________________________________ */

**//THIS WORKS AS IT SHOULD**

<?php

  $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'slides',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

   $sliderTitle = get_the_title();

  $slideNumber = 0;

  while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $the_query->the_post();

  $slideNumber++;

  $attachment_id = get_field('slider_image');
  $sizeSm = "slider-image-sm";
  $sizeMd = "slider-image-md";
  $sizeLg = "slider-image-Lg";
  $image_attributes_sm = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeSm );
  $image_attributes_md = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeMd );
  $image_attributes_lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeLg );

?>

// Set-up Responsive Image loading and allow for full-page background image slider

.slider-major .slider-main.slider-homepage .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
  background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_sm[0]; ?>");
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-homepage .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>{
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-homepage .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 100em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-homepage .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_lg[0]; ?>");
  }
}

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>






/* ___________PROJECT SLIDER IMAGE SET-UP________________________________________ */

 **//THIS IS THE PROBLEM. ONLY LOOPS THROUGH A FEW PROJECTS. THERE WILL BE UPWARDS OF 15 PROJECTS ON THE SITE AND ONLY 4-5 OF THEM WORK TO SHOW IMAGES**

<?php

  $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'projects'
  ));


  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();


  $slideNumber = 0;

  while (has_sub_field('project_slider_images')) :

  $slideNumber++;

  $attachment_id = get_sub_field('project_slider_image');
  $sizeSm = "slider-image-sm";
  $sizeMd = "slider-image-md";
  $sizeLg = "slider-image-Lg";
  $image_attributes_sm = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeSm );
  $image_attributes_md = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeMd );
  $image_attributes_lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeLg );

?>

// Set-up Responsive Image loading and allow for full-page background image slider

.slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
  background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_sm[0]; ?>");
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>{
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 100em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-<?php echo the_ID(); ?> .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_lg[0]; ?>");
  }
}

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>





/* ___________PRACTICE SLIDER IMAGE SET-UP____________________________________ */
```

**//THIS WORKS AS IT SHOULD**

```
<?php

  $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'practice_slides',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

   $sliderTitle = get_the_title();

  $slideNumber = 0;

  while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $the_query->the_post();

  $slideNumber++;

  $attachment_id = get_field('practice_slider_image');
  $sizeSm = "slider-image-sm";
  $sizeMd = "slider-image-md";
  $sizeLg = "slider-image-Lg";
  $image_attributes_sm = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeSm );
  $image_attributes_md = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeMd );
  $image_attributes_lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $sizeLg );

?>

// Set-up Responsive Image loading and allow for full-page background image slider

.slider-major .slider-main.slider-practice .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
  background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_sm[0]; ?>");
}
@media only screen and (min-height: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-practice .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>{
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 45em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-practice .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_md[0]; ?>");
  }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 100em) {
  .slider-major .slider-main.slider-practice .slide-<?php echo $slideNumber; ?> {
    background-image: url("<?php echo $image_attributes_lg[0]; ?>");
  }
}
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: may be problum with browser compatibility  in chrome looking fine

Comment: I'm looking in multiple browsers, not loading in any